# Как остановить @bot.message_handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Создаю бота на python 3 с помощью библеотеки telebot. И вот задался вопросом как остановить message hendler, например ты запустил message_handler что-бы пользователь ввёл своё имя и потом нужно остановить его, что-бы если он опять что-то введёт это "что-то" не должно запоминатся.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome_employer(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите Ваше имя: ")
```

При запуске команды /start вам приложиться ввести имя. То что вы напишите в ответе то и сохраниться, все что будите писать дальше не будет сохраняться.
Например вы напишите "Коля", отправить, потом напишите еще "Саша", он сохранит только "Коля".